# What should this poor guy be told?

Tags: epidemiology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the chances my wife has lupus?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45807/what-are-the-chances-my-wife-has-lupus)

A day or two ago a man posted a question on math.stackexchenge about whether his wife likely has lupus, given the diagnosis. First,  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256079/what-are-the-chances-my-wife-has-lupus

It appears I will be able to post a screenshot of the question and of my answer, which i deleted after the OP expressed a lack of satisfaction.

However, the screenshots take up quite a lot of room, so I will try to make a question here. On the odd chance that this man ever looks at his MSE question again, is there anything else of value he could be told? Note that there are two answers after mine, explaining rather better than i did that he has not given enough information.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=